# Eliminate empty Inputs through JQuery

Tags: jquery, input

```
var totsub = $('.class1').parent().find( "div").length;
```

Question is about the emptiness of the input box.

```
<div class="class1">
                        <input type="text" name="" value="" class="someclass">
                    </div>
```

Let's say there are 10 divs now out of which few have numerical value only in few(filled) and rest are empty. How can we filter so that we get  only filled div values in `totsub`?

Answer (score 0):

Use children() and 'input:text[value=""]'

```
var totsub = $('.class1').parent().find( "div").children("'input:text[value=""]'").length;
```

Comment: It works may be you didn’t encapsulate code with document ready event

Comment: Question is about the emptiness of the input box.

Comment: Thanks, but the premise is we have to fetch nonempty div in real time. Will this fetch non-empty div's?

Comment: This s still unable to find the filled inputs, but it is taking into picture all the inputs. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>1</div>
    <div></div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div></div>
    <div>4</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
var array  = {};
        $('div').each(function () {
    array =(this.innerHTML);
    console.log(array);
});

    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```